# UploadFile: This operation is not supported in the WCF Test Client Because it uses type ClientFileInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding, filestream

I am fairly new to WCF services and would appreciate some help with this. I am trying to run the WCF as a service and have a ASP.net client on a different machine be able to upload files to it by connecting to the WCF service.

I am testing it with a simple uploading setup (from [here](http://www.seesharpdot.net/?p=214)) and it works fine if I just reference the WCF Service as a "dll" but if I try to run in it as a WCF Service it gives me an error for the "UploadFile" method by stating that it is not supported.

Exact message with the red X on the method name: This operation is not supported in the WCF Test Client Because it uses type FileUploadMessage.

I start by creating a WCF Service application in Visual Studio 2012 and have the following in my interface (IUploadService.cs):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUploadService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UploadFile(FileUploadMessage request);
}

[MessageContract]
public class FileUploadMessage
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream FileByteStream;
}
```

Its implemented like so (UploadService.svc.cs):

```
public void UploadFile(FileUploadMessage request)
{
    Stream fileStream = null;
    Stream outputStream = null;

    try
    {
         fileStream = request.FileByteStream;

         string rootPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootPath"].ToString();

         DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);
         if (!dirInfo.Exists)
         {
             dirInfo.Create();
         }

         // Create the file in the filesystem - change the extension if you wish, 
         // or use a passed in value from metadata ideally

         string newFileName = Path.Combine(rootPath, Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg");

         outputStream = new FileInfo(newFileName).OpenWrite();
         const int bufferSize = 1024;
         byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

         int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

         while (bytesRead > 0)
         {
             outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
             bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         }
     }
     catch (IOException ex)
     {
          throw new FaultException<IOException>(ex, new FaultReason(ex.Message));
     }
     finally
     {
         if (fileStream != null)
         {
             fileStream.Close();
         }
         if (outputStream != null)
         {
             outputStream.Close();
         }
     }
} // end UploadFile
```

From the looks of it should work but from what I understood by looking at several stackoverflow and other forum questions it seems that WCF doesn't support Stream even though we can have a binding of type streaming. I am confused about this and what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After communicating with Adam on his [blog](http://www.seesharpdot.net/?p=214) where I got the code from I realized that I was testing this the wrong way. Everything was implemented correctly but using the WCF Test Client was messing things up. Just launching the project and consuming it by adding it as a web reference to "Service.svc" worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks @M Khan I was crazy in this error since read your answer :)

Comment: Is it means I can't test my upload method using WCF test client because of Stream member?

Comment: At the time I was working on this issue it wasn't possible to test it using the WCF test client. I am not sure if it has been updated since or not. If it can't be tested using the test client then the other obvious way would be to just consume it and see if it works.